# Where are the built-in rails generators documented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I have yet to find a pointer to the authoritative list of built-in rails generators.  What does `rails generate helper` do?  How about `rails generate resource`?  What's the distinction between `rails generate scaffold` and `rails generate scaffold_controller`?  Etc...

I've found answers to each of these one at a time, but it would be nice to know where to look for the entire set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a comprehensive list, but one can always consult the "authoritative documentation" which is a euphemism for the source code.  You can look the USAGE file for each subdirectory under:

```
https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/
```

It's not ideal, but it should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Run `rails generate --help`, which will output something like:

```
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  controller
  generator
  ...

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:devise

SomeGem:
  some_gem:some_type_of_file
  ...
```

All available generators (including those defined by gems) are listed. You can use the `-h` option, as described above, to get more info about specific generators (e.g. `rails g assets -h`).

If this doesn't answer your question your best bet is to consult the source code, as fearless_fool recommends. Visit https://github.com/rails/rails/find/master, type in "generator" and Ctrl-F for what you're looking for.